# How to animate the action bar tab titles when they are swiped onto?

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation

[image: Example image]

When the tab is selected then tab title enlarges in size, how to imitate that effect?

I have searched all web for this but didn't found anything.

Comment: Please provide us with code you have already tried or have for your project

Comment: It is not my project,I am simply trying to replicate it but am stuck on the animation step,I know that it uses a tab layout with a view pager.